# The correct way of saving data inside the MongoDB docker-compose.yml

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've been reading some blog posts and answers to find a way to keep the data in a MongoDB container even after deleting and re-building.

Below is how I would do, but I am concerned with losing all data even after doing this, so I wasn't able to actually test it. Is this the correct way to do it? Will this keep my data even after I do something like `docker system prune` and `docker-compose build` again?

```
# Docker Compose
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db <------- added this part
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done will retain data between container restarts as well as prune.
The volume will only be deleted if you delete all your volumes explicitly, or prune your volumes.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db

volumes:
    data-volume:
      name: db-data
```

Make sure to give your volumes name explicitly, otherwise you'll find yourself having multiple anonymous volumes created during your experimentation.

Comment: Thank you. If my docker-compose is already up without that change, shall I make that change and re-built it before trying to restart or prune?

Comment: I just tried this and `docker-system prune`d after rebuilding the `docker-compose` but the data were all gone. I backed it up, so I can just restore it, but it seems like the volume is not working as I intended. Am I missing something?

Comment: When I used `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' <id>`, I get `[{volume db-data /var/lib/docker/volumes/db-data/_data /data/db local rw true } {volume 8e4e0238d6ddcbcb3d78609a06c10476fe27369a4b40726c997c3e2bf3babe72 /var/lib/docker/volumes/8e4e0238d6ddcbcb3d78609a06c10476fe27369a4b40726c997c3e2bf3babe72/_data /data/configdb local  true }]` which seems correct. Why is it deleting my data though?